# Android: change windowBackground to something that scales right

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native so my android native knowledge is close to non-existent.

Following a tutorial online I was able to create a splash screen for my app by setting windowBackground to an image(bitmap) for my main activity.

This works well but the image is not scaled property(as the gravity set on the bitmap image is set to fill and aspect ratio is not respected).

Tweaking the gravity prop on the bitmap image didn't yield anything great.

Can someone point out the proper way to get this to work? I have seen some answers here on SO but must require creating a layout and I have no idea where that's supposed to fit in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this tutorial about splash screens for Android Applications (The right way to make it work):

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Just follow step by step and you´re done, I did it before and works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks. I was using an image with my logo in the center(which was getting resized badly). I switched to just having my logo in the middle and a background color fit the earlier image.

Comment: Oh btw, is there a way to resize the image? Its looking a bit smaller than its suppose to

Comment: There are some attributes (height, width) for <item> tag in your splash layout, but only works for api +23. For lower versions, you'll have to change the drawable icon size in some external editor for images.